# Как реализовать таймауты в запросах?

Tags: c#

Хочу следить за обновлением сайта, как мне это сделать? Что бы моя запущенная программа с определенной периодичностью заходила на сайт и проверяла, есть ли там что-нибудь новенькое.

Вот пример кода. Но программа тормозит.

```
  while(true)

        {
        // Проверка существования файла.
        if (File.Exists("C:\\0.txt"))
        {
            var m = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\0.txt");
            foreach (var st in m)
            {
                if (st.Contains("Day")) {
                    Shutdown();
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
```

Как это делается более изящно?

Comment: Добавьте код в ваше сообщение. Чтобы окружающие могли прочувствовать вашу проблему

Comment: Кода пока нет, мне нужно просто узнать куда копать

Comment: В чем собственно проблема? Добавить таймер, с интервалом в час, по событию от таймера заходить на сайт ..

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) вам в помощь. А чтобы не тормозило, советую почитать про потоки [Threads](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/thread_and_files/1/1_4.php). В шарпе есть еще простенький компонент, но он вам помощет - это BackgroundWorker

Comment: "Но программа тормозит." - то есть? что конкретно вам не нравится в работе программы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Планировать действия можно двумя способами:

1. Через таймеры ([Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) или [Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)) внутри приложения. Такие приложения делают как [Windows-сервис](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zt39148a.aspx) и они работают постоянно.

   ```
   private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

   public static void Main()
   {
       aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
       aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
       aTimer.Interval = 2000;
       aTimer.Enabled = true;

       Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
   }
   ```
2. Настроить расписание вызова вашей программы в [планировщике Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). Программа становится проще. Подходит для редких операций. Например, проверка обновлений пару раз в день.

Что вы понимаете под обновление сайта? Обновление одной конкретной страницы или всех?

1. Если одной, то все [просто](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx).

   ```
   var siteText = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://mysite.ru/news.html");
   ```
2. Если же вы хотите все страницы, то вам нужен аналог [WebCrawler](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82), но только для страниц одного сайта. Работает он так:

   1. заходит на сайт по стартовым адресам;
   2. загружает страницы из списка и ищет на них ссылки на новые страницы;
   3. повторяет пункт 2 для новых ссылок;

   При этом используется база данных со списком адресов, очередь планирования заданий для скачивания, многопоточная загрузка страниц...

   В этой статье дан пример на [C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13486/A-Simple-Crawler-Using-C-Sockets).

Работать с содержимым страниц в формате html очень удобно при помощи библиотечки [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). В этом примере из html документа выбираются все ссылки:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(var node in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"]))
{
    var href = node["href"];
    Console.WriteLine(href);
}
```